# How to read content from td with simple html dom

Tags: php, html, dom, scrape

This is my code:

```html
<tr>
  <td class="text">
    <div><a href="somethinghref">Something</a></div>
  </td>
  <td>Something2</td>
  <td>Something3</td>
</tr>
```

I want to get content from td and return in single line like this
Something - Something2

Comment: Please be more specific. You want to Get content where ?

Comment: with javascript ?

Comment: You mean with `simple_html_dom` library?

Comment: I need to foreach results and return content from first td and second in single line ... this <tr> is one of many ....

Comment: What you have tried so far? Where is you PHP code?

Comment: resolved, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

For HTML DOM manipulation there is a library called jQuery you can easily Travers the HTML dome with that.
and Bellow is the solution of your problem.

```
   <!doctype html>
   <html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Untitled Document</title>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>

 <body>
 <table id="tblNewAttendees">
  <tr>
  <td class="text"><div><a href="somethinghref">Something</a></div</td>
  <td>Something2</td>
  <td>Something3</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
  <div class="table-content"></div>
   <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
 var content ='';
 $('#tblNewAttendees tr').each(function() {

$.each(this.cells, function(){
    //alert($(this).text());
    content+=$(this).text()+" - ";
    });

   });
   $(".table-content").html(content);
   });
</script>
 </body>
 </html>
```